How to differentiate between Map, Array, String, etc... in XPath 3.1?
Is there a function that can test (or return) the type of .? For example:
( root(), (), "a", 1, map{}, array{} ) ! unknown:type-of(.)

node
sequence
string
number
map
array


You can use the "instance of" operator to test whether a value matches a particular type, for example if ($a instance of map(*)) ....
There is no function to determine "the type" of a value because many values do not have a single explicit type in this sense: consider for example the value ("a", 23, true()). The type system is a lattice rather than a hierarchy.
